# How to flatten a casted tuple of dictionaries into one dictionary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dictionary, tuples, tensorflow-datasets

I have the following function, which creates a dataset, from two separate dictionaries, by making them a tuple. For example:

```
features = {'input_ids': some.tf.tensor 'input_mask': some.tf.tensor 'segment_ids': some.tf.tensor}
dict2 = {'labels': some.tf.tensor}

support_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, dataset["labels"]))
```

what this does is that it casts the concatenation of the two slices as a tuple:

```
support_dataset = ({'input_ids': ..., 'input_mask': ..., 'segment_ids': ...}, {'labels': ...})
```

what I want is a single dictionary and not a tuple `{'input_ids': ..., 'input_mask': ..., 'segment_ids': ..., 'labels': ...}` so I can look up the keys by their names. I do not think I can let go of the `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, dataset["labels"]))` function so is their a way to unpack the tuple while casting it inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `update()` method of `dictionary`.

```
features = {'input_ids': some.tf.tensor, 'input_mask': some.tf.tensor, 'segment_ids': some.tf.tensor}
dict2 = {'labels': some.tf.tensor}
features.update(dict2)
```

```
features
{'input_ids': some.tf.tensor, 'input_mask': some.tf.tensor, 'segment_ids': some.tf.tensor, 'labels': some.tf.tensor}
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating a function like this:

`def merge_dico(d1,d2):
    for key, val in d1.items():
        d2[key] = val
    return d2`